# Loading different stateless Spring beans per request

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am trying to find out what's the best way to use Spring (or not) for loading beans on demand. Here's an example. Let's say that there are two types of mechanic beans

```
@Bean("japanese-mechanic")
public Mechanic japaneseMechanic(){
  return new JapaneseMechanicImpl
}

@Bean("german-mechanic")
public Mechanic germanMechanic(){
  return new GermanMechanicImpl
}
```

My question is how do I load the right bean per request. Currently, the way we do it is using "Context.getBean", so it would look something like

```
String beanName = request.getParameter("typeOfCar") + "-mechanic";
Mechanic mechanic = Context.getBean(beanName,Mechanic.class);
```

I understand that calling "Context.getBean" this way violates IOC, so looking for a better way to do this, if available. Can someone suggest some alternatives to doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid accessing the context directly by wiring all the mechanics to your own map like the following:

```
@Autowired
Map<String, Mechanic> mechanics;

Mechanic mechanic = mechanics.get(beanName);
```

So instead of fetching the bean from the context map, you autowire them to your own map and fetch them from there. Could be considered better style, or if you have requirements that you can't access the context directly.

Comment: I don't have any such restrictions on using Context

Comment: @Seagull well you said you didn't want to use Context.getBean(). This is the alternative, even though it's basically technically equivalent. It's not completely equivalent though, since you're still letting Spring handle the autowiring, so you can for example mock the map (of course you can mock the context too).

Comment: Yeah I understand what you're doing there, just not entirely convinced on whether this is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to autowire a bean based on a request parameter directly in Spring. You could always write a handler yourself if you want to blow your 2 lines of code into 200 lines.

Comment: Haha, very unlikely 